# Is memcached supposed to take this long?

Tags: php, memcached

I've compared these two pieces of code:

**Test 1:**

```
$time = microtime(true);

$memcached = new Memcached();
$memcached->addServer('localhost', 11211);

for($i=1;$i<=1000;$i++){
   $result = $memcached->get('test');
}

echo (microtime(true) - $time)*1000;
```

Resulting time: 50.509929656982

---

**Test 2:**

```
$time = microtime(true);

$memcached = new Memcached();
$memcached->addServer('localhost', 11211);

for($i=1;$i<=1000;$i++){
   $result = 'just me';
}

echo (microtime(true) - $time)*1000;
```

Resulting time: 0.3209114074707

Is memcached supposed to take this long?

Comment: Can you try `$memcached->connect()` instead of `$memcached->addServer()`? This will ensure that connection is made before you actually proceed to `get`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did kind of a lot of confusing math there.  I don't think your question is clear at all.

It looks like you got 50.509929656982ms after multiplying the original answer by 1,000.  So I'm going to multiply that back to your original answer of ~50,510µs.  Now, that was for 1,000 requests, so the average request returned in ~50µs.

Now, if you actually want to grab 1,000 items, you'll it in a single multiget request, which will reduce that time per-item average considerably.

If you're asking if the time to form and transmit a network request and get the network response, parse it and return it is expected to be slower than a NOOP assignment in a tight loop then, yeah.

If you're asking if 50µs is fast or slow... that's really up to you.

Answer (score 0):

On a typical memcached setup I would expect almost every operation to finish in 1ms or less. I would recommend checking to see what your network latency is and then profiling the client to see how much time the client spends actually processing the operations. If you can rule out those being slow then you might have some kind of server side issue.